# Is River Song based on Mara Jade?

Tags: star-wars, doctor-who, star-wars-legends, river-song, character-similarity

[Warning: Star Wars *and* Doctor Who spoilers!]

A [post](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/whos-that-star-wars-lady-we-break-down-the-latest-casting-rumors/) on Barnes and Noble's sci-fi-fantasy blog had an interesting observation about **Mara Jade**:

> Introduced as the would-be-assiasin of Luke Skywalker, she ends up marrying him. (Did Steven Moffat base River Song from Doctor Who off of Mara Jade? Hmmm…)

[image]
[River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song) and [Mara Jade](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mara_Jade_Skywalker) do seem to be very similar:

- trained to assassinate the main hero
- fell in love with target instead
- ends ups marrying target
- still managed to fulfill assassination mission by instead killing a
  decoy/duplicate of the target
- red-ish hair (Mara has red hair, River is a sort of
  strawberry-blonde)
- is a fan favorite warrior
- posseses rare skills the main hero also has (Mara wields a lightsaber and uses the Force, River can fly the TARDIS and is part Time-Lord)

I could go on, but basically these two characters seem way too similar to be just a coincidence. **Is River Song based on Mara Jade?**

Comment: Bernice Summerfield seems like a more likely inspiration.

Comment: This is hardly [a new idea](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InLoveWithTheMark)

Comment: Damnit @Phantom42 for the love of God put a warning! XD

Comment: Anybody have Russel T. Davies or Tim Zahn's home #?

Comment: @Politank-Z - this one?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernice_Summerfield

Comment: @EngrStudent Yes.Archaeologist, hooked up with The Doctor, time sequence shenanigans with The Doctor's brother... not to mention, Davies liked reusing ideas from extended/non-canon sources which he liked.

Comment: @Politank-Z - that sounds like a plausible answer.  If you provided another case where something analogous happened then it would be an even stronger answer.

Comment: Just a speculation by way of a web comic. As for something analogous: the re-introduction of the Cybermen was heavily based on an audio adventure, to the point that the writers of the original work were credited. Kate Stewart is directly from a non-canon miniseries. In reusing canon, *Rose* was very much like a sped-up, modern, *Spearhead From Space*. I don't think this amounts to a complete answer, but if you'd care to run with it and attempt one yourself, you have my blessing.

Comment: River is not part Time Lord

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Her [page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song) says "Species: Human, Time Lord" and that "travelling through the Time Vortex (...) gave her some Time Lord DNA". I'd say that makes her part Time Lord (since her DNA is part of her).

Comment: @redcaio that's not backed up by anything though. That's the problem with relying on fan sites for information.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack They _say_ her DNA is "human plus Time Lord" about 32 min.s into season 6 ep. 7 "Good Man Goes to War". River ["has both human and Time Lord DNA."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Good_Man_Goes_to_War) River has some Time Lord DNA _and_ she has even regenerated a few times, how can you say she's _not_ part Time Lord?

Comment: Unless Steven Moffat fesses up some day in an interview, there is no possible answer to this question.

Comment: @phantom42 "This is hardly a new idea" If you're saying Moffat was simply using a common trope, then I'd say that's an answer. __I'd upvote and accept an answer like that__. :)

Answer (score 3):

**No.** [In Love with the Mark](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InLoveWithTheMark) (warning: TvTrope) is a common trope and there is no reason for River Song to have been specifically based off of any previous iteration of that trope.